# Excel Power Query: How can I let Excel errors pass through without getting edited?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I've tried researching this but I can't seem to find this particular problem..

I'm bringing data from one workbook into another via Power Query. In the source workbook some cells have #VALUE! errors, and my users need to see those in the destination workbook, so that they know there's a problem. I am not using any "Replace Errors" steps in the query. Excel shows a generic "Error" in the cell in the Query Editor, but in the destination table, the cell is simply empty. Is there a way to have Excel not do anything with the error, and show it as a #VALUE! error in the destination workbook?

Query code is as follows:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("Q:\03 Master Price Sheets\Update 17.11.7\Material Price Sheet v2, 171208.xlsm"), null, true),
    Materials_Table = Source{[Item="Materials",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Materials_Table,{{"Price List P/N", type text}, {"Business Works P/N", type text}, {"Bend Type", type text}, {"Wt/Ft", type number}, {"Do not use or delete 1", type any}, {"Do not use or delete 2", type any}, {"Do not use or delete 3", type any}, {"Stock or NonStock", type text}, {"Mat'l Type", type text}, {"Mat'l Cost", type any}, {"Instructions", type text}, {"Do not use or delete 4", type any}, {"Mat'l Color", type text}, {"Do not use or delete 5", type any}, {"Vendor", type any}, {"Do not use or delete 6", type any}, {"Web", Int64.Type}, {"Type", type text}, {"Flange", Int64.Type}, {"Gauge", Int64.Type}, {"Gauge Group", type any}, {"Web to Look Up", type any}, {"Web Group", type any}, {"Flange to Look Up", type any}, {"Labor Times Base Material (Auto-Selected)", type any}, {"Labor Times Base Material (Override)", type any}, {"Material to Look Up", type any}, {"Base Labor from Table", type any}, {"Base Labor (Override)", type any}, {"Base Labor", type any}, {"Extra Person Lookup Key", type text}, {"EP Min Length", Int64.Type}, {"EP Factor", type number}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Do not use or delete 1", "Do not use or delete 2", "Do not use or delete 3", "Do not use or delete 4", "Do not use or delete 5", "Do not use or delete 6", "Web", "Type", "Flange", "Gauge", "Gauge Group", "Web to Look Up", "Web Group", "Flange to Look Up", "Labor Times Base Material (Auto-Selected)", "Labor Times Base Material (Override)", "Material to Look Up", "Base Labor from Table", "Base Labor (Override)", "Extra Person Lookup Key"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: What if you use the last solution on this [link](https://blog.gbrueckl.at/2013/12/error-handling-in-power-query/)

Comment: @virtualdvid The error column with the reason and message doesn't seem to exist when the error is not produced in the query editor but loaded in already containing an error.

Comment: I did some text and it worked. I have the same problem but those extra fields appeared when I clicked **Load more** in the expand box.

Comment: @virtualdvid Odd. I can't get those fields at all even if I click Load more.